# How to show section number shown in \paragraph?

Tags: sections-paragraphs

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\titleformat{\paragraph} [hang] {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries {\theparagraph} {1em} {} %%
```

When I use `\paragraph` underneath a `\subsubsection`, the `\paragraph` doesn't have a section number before it.

For example, if I have

```
\subsubsection{Yo}
\paragraph{Test}
```

The PDF would look something like:

```
4.4.3 Yo
          Test
```

But what I want to have is:

```
4.4.3 Yo
 4.4.3.1  Test
```

Does anyone have any idea how to?

Comment: Works properly for me, once you add a closing `}` after `\bfseries`.

Comment: welcome to the site, but questions are always a lot easier to answer if you provide a complete small document that shows the problem, not just fragments of code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, it helped me debug the problem!

I used a latex template, and found this:

```
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\hspace*{-1em}}
```

I'm new to Latex, so not sure what it does, but I commented them out and it fixed my problem.

Comment: The code `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\hspace*{-1em}}` basically redefined what happens when `\paragraph` gets invoked, essentially removing the standard numbered label, and replacing it with a negative horizontal tab.

Comment: `secnumdepth` defines how deep in the sectioning scheme (`\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`, etc.) the label numbering goes.  The default value depends on the documentclass